# HTTP401 when access sharepoint web service using Java HttpClient

Tags: web-services

the code are as follows:

```
private static EndpointReference targetEPR = new EndpointReference(  
            "http://sharepoint01/_vti_bin/lists.asmx");  
ServiceClient sender = new ServiceClient();

List authSchema = new ArrayList(); 
HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
auth.setDomain(""); 
auth.setUsername("");
auth.setPassword(""); 
auth.setHost("");
auth.setPort(80);
List authPrefs = new ArrayList(1); 
authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.NTLM); 
auth.setAuthSchemes(authPrefs);
sender.getOptions()
      .setAction("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CheckOutFile");
sender.getOptions().setTo(targetEPR); 
sender.getOptions().setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(1000000); 
sender.getOptions()
      .setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth); 
sender.getOptions()
      .setProperty (HTTPConstants.HTTP_PROTOCOL_VERSION, HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_10);

OMFactory fac = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
OMNamespace omNs = fac.createOMNamespace("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", "");
OMElement data = fac.createOMElement("CheckOutFile", omNs);
OMElement inner = fac.createOMElement("pageUrl", omNs);
inner.setText("http://sharepoint01/Shared Documents/fpga.doc");
OMElement inner1 = fac.createOMElement("checkoutToLocal", omNs);
inner.setText("true"); OMElement inner2 = fac.createOMElement("lastmodified", omNs);
inner.setText(""); data.addChild(inner); data.addChild(inner1); data.addChild(inner2);

OMElement result = sender.sendReceive；
```

and the error code is

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport
>   error: 401 Error: Unauthorized at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:311)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:200)
>   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:76)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:400)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:225)
>   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:438) at
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:540)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:521)
>   at test01.getResult(test01.java:113) at test01.main(test01.java:182)

Comment: Take a look in the IIS logs, to see what kind of 401 is thrown (401.1, 401.2, ...). This is maybe a server configuration issue. Also, please explains what kind of authentication you have set up on the SharePoint farm, especially if you have setup the web application to use claims authentication

Answer (score 1):

Not a Java expert but you are not setting the domain, username and password when making the connection. TherefOre the request is sent anonymously and is not authenticated and you get a 401 error

Comment: Many thanks for you quick reply. So you mean the setting in my code is invalid ? And do you know how to setting the domain, username and password exactly? And could you give me some example code?

Comment: I believe in Java you have to ask for the credentials. In '.net you can use a default set which users the current users login details. I found this post http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html I can see from your code that you have calls to setusername() setdomain and setpassword() I would try populating those to get it working and then look at how you could get the credentials from the user in a nice way.